# Why does onload cause my image switch to flicker?

Tags: javascript

For some reason, when I use the attribute onload on my img tag, it causes my images to flicker. Ideally, when I load the page, an image is displayed and when I refresh the page, the image is changed. 
Here's my tag as well as the function for it:

**HTML**

```
<img id="randomimage" onload="randomImg()" src="images/carmainpic.jpg" alt="main pic of car"/>
```

**JavasScript**

```
function randomImg(){
    var images=["images/carmainpic.jpg","images/carmainpic2.jpg","images/carmainpic3.jpg"];
    var num=Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    document.getElementById("randomimage").src=images[num];
}
```

Comment: Does it flicker just once when the page finishes loading, or constantly?

Comment: It flickers constantly :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `randomImg` function is called every time the image loads. You can use a flag variable to make sure that you only change the image once:

```
var changed = false;
function randomImg(){
    if (!changed) {
        changed = true;
        var images=["images/carmainpic.jpg","images/carmainpic2.jpg","images/carmainpic3.jpg"];
        var num=Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
        document.getElementById("randomimage").src=images[num];
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just pass `this` into it (`onload="randomImg(this)"`) and then `img.onload = null;`.

Answer (score 4):

Because the function you're calling changes the image's `src` to a random pick from the array, triggering a new `load` event, which changes the `src` randomly again, etc. On at least some browsers the cycle probably stops when you happen to assign the URL the image already has, too.

**If** your goal is to just show one of those images, at random, you can do that by leaving `src` off the `img` entirely and then adding it (once) with script (either immediately following the `img` in order to avoid your layout having to be adjusted when you add it, or in script at the end of the page if you prefer; no need to wait for any event):

```
<img id="randomimage" alt="main pic of car"/>
<script>
(function() {
    var images=["images/carmainpic.jpg","images/carmainpic2.jpg","images/carmainpic3.jpg"];
    var num=Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length); // <== Note change, so adding images to the array Just Works
    document.getElementById("randomimage").src=images[num];
})();
</script>
```

Even if you put the script immediately after the `<img ...>` tag, the `img` element **will** be available to the script. So your choice whether to do it inline or with the other scripts at the end of the page.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are listening to the `load` event on the image, instead of the page.

> ```
> onload="randomImg()"
> ```

So, as soon as the first image loads, it triggers the function `randomImg` which causes change of `src` attribute on the image. So the browser will attempt to assign a new image to the element, and yet another load event is triggered, which repeats the entire cycle.

---

Instead, if you want to choose a random image when the page loads, you can listen to [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event on the document, and choose a random image.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var images=["images/carmainpic.jpg","images/carmainpic2.jpg","images/carmainpic3.jpg"];
    var num=Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    document.getElementById("randomimage").src=images[num];
    
    console.log("Showing: " + images[num]);
});
```

```html
<img id="randomimage"  src="images/carmainpic.jpg" alt="main pic of car"/>
```

---

**Note**: Since you are selecting a random image, it is not guaranteed that you will always get a different image when the page is refreshed. Instead, if you must get a different image on refreshing the page, you can perhaps persist the image identifier in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage), and use that to determine the next image to display.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use $(document).ready(function(){}) to do that. Because you want when charge the page that function execute it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  
  function randomImg(){
      var images=["https://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/romantic.jpg","https://www.psdstack.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/featured-copyright-free-mages.jpg","http://shaebaxter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Life-of-Pix-free-stock-photos-sea-peaople-water-waves-back-Sunset-Joshua-earle-1024x682.jpg"];
      var num=Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
      document.getElementById("randomimage").src=images[num];
  }
  
  randomImg();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="randomimage" src="" alt="main pic of car"/>
```